# Mongoose $regex doesn't work with new RegExp?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having troubles making a $regex query with Mongoose;

The following works just fine:

```
Media.count(
    { "filename" : 
    { $regex: /placeholder(-)?(\w+.)?.(\w+)?$/gm } }, 
    function(err, res){
...
```

The following does not work:

```
var xp = new RegExp("placeholder(-)?(\w+.)?.(\w+)?$", "gm")

Media.count(
    { "filename" : 
    { $regex: xp } }, 
    function(err, res){
...
```

I also tried the following that does not work either:

```
var xp = new RegExp("placeholder(-)?(\w+.)?.(\w+)?$")

Media.count(
    { "filename" : 
    { $regex: xp, $options: 'gm' } }, 
    function(err, res){
...
```

For some reason I feel like Mongoose doesn't take RegExp objects ? The problem I'm having is the fact that I need to replace 'placeholder' with a variable, therefore I need to use RegExp to get this done...

Any one ever had that problem before

Answer (score 1):

I just found out about my error, adding it here if anyone else have the same problem:

When using new RegExp, you need to make sure to escape your backslashes this way:

**Right way:**

```
var xp = new RegExp("placeholder(-)?(\\w+.)?.(\\w+)?$")
```

**Wrong way:**

```
var xp = new RegExp("placeholder(-)?(\w+.)?.(\w+)?$")
```